# javascript redirect & replace

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, redirect

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var r = window.location.href;
    if (r.match(/#|%23/)) {
        r = r.replace(/#|%23/gi, \"@NUM@\");
        window.location.href = r;
    }
</script>
```

This script will redirect the page and replace `#` symbols with `@NUM@` in the URL (don't ask why)...

I'm trying to modify the script so it doesn't replace "#" if it is at the end of the URL

example:

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?f=abc#def
```

will become

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?f=abc@NUM@def
```

But this link:

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?f=abc#def#
```

will become:

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?f=abc@NUM@def#
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead to guarantee that there is at least one more character:

```
/(#|%23)(?=.)/g
```

Comment: Perhaps `(?!$)` (not end of line) would be the more obvious option, but both do the same job.

Comment: Only problem with your lookahead is that . will also match a space, so if the # is at the end of the url with a space e.g. [http://www.example.com/test.php?f=abc@NUM@def# ] this means it will still replace the end #. Perhaps replace the . with # in the lookahead so (?=#)

Comment: @libertaire: That depends.  Which of those functions do you want to not match spaces?